# JHtmlBehavior::polyfill not found Error

Tags: joomla-3.7

I have just installed `CentOS 7` and installed LAMP and have downloaded Joomla and extracted the zip and granted permissions to folders etc.  If I navigate to localhost I get an error of

> JHtmlBehavior::polyfill not found

What is causing this error to be displayed?  This is a fresh OS install and a fresh Joomla install

**EDIT**
I am running php 7.1.4 & CentOS 7 & MariaDB

Answer (score 1):

This problem happens when you are using PHP 7 and IE 8 as a browser (or less). See [this post](http://www.itoctopus.com/jhtmlbehavior-polyfill-not-found-fatal-error-on-joomla) for more details. Switch to another browser to resolve this issue. Joomla will likely release a fix to the problem soon.